# Error finding the mediapipe lib but it is present in the folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mediapipe

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\shash\Desktop\Extras\Traning_Placement\Projects_python\hand_tracking\Hand_Tracking_Min.py",
> line 2, in 
> import mediapipe as mp   File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe_*init*_.py",
> line 17, in 
> import mediapipe.python.solutions as solutions   File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions_*init*_.py",
> line 17, in 
> import mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_styles   File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\drawing_styles.py",
> line 20, in 
> from mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils import DrawingSpec   File
> "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\drawing_utils.py",
> line 25, in 
> from mediapipe.framework.formats import detection_pb2   File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\detection_pb2.py",
> line 16, in 
> from mediapipe.framework.formats import location_data_pb2 as mediapipe_dot_framework_dot_formats_dot_location__data__pb2   File
> "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\location_data_pb2.py",
> line 16, in 
> from mediapipe.framework.formats.annotation import rasterization_pb2 as
> mediapipe_dot_framework_dot_formats_dot_annotation_dot_rasterization__pb2
> File
> "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\annotation\rasterization_pb2.py",
> line 36, in 
> _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(   File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py",
> line 560, in **new**
> _message.Message._CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile() TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly. If this call came from a
> _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0. If you cannot immediately
> regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
>
> 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
> 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

And this is the program I wrote:

```py
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success,img=cap.read()



    cv2.imshow("Image",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It seems like it isn't mediapipe that the error is about; but a dependent package (protobuf).  Did you try the 2nd option before you try the 1st option?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today, I tried to run the code in google Colab in the meantime and it worked well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can update the version of protobuf.

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install protobuf==3.20.1
```